# Why can't I nest these headings in HTML? (beginner level)

Tags: html, header

I'm doing some of these basic lessons for HTML on Codeacademy, and I've hit my first round-block. Why doesn't this construct work properly?

```
<h1>
        First text.
        <h4> 
           I'm a different size than the first text.
        </h4> 
        I'm not the same size as the first text. Why?
</h1>
```

I don't really know what headings are. Code Academy hasn't really explained much.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to look at my n00b question.

Comment: Headings are a way of styling text within your document. There should be no need to nest headings - what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @zacdav Yes, it can be used for styling, but their main goal is to subdivise the page.

Comment: hmm... I was surprised to see such embedding h4 inside of h1 - I've never see something like this, headers were always titles of some sort, so you should not put one inside another, but after checking html reference, this is allowed. in my opinion however use <span> for just text size differentiation -  it will be more standard and there will be no issues with different browsers

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a good reference for this, but it looks like nesting these tags is simply not allowed.

Browsers are pretty lenient about what they'll attempt to display. In this case, I believe the browser closes the `h1` tag for you when it encounters the `h4` tag. Then it quietly ignores the spurious `</h1>` it finds later—remember that it already closed it for you.

So the actual elements I see in Chrome are roughly this:

```
<h1>First text.</h1>
<h4>I'm a different size than the first text.</h4>
I'm not the same size as the first text. Why?
```

You can see this yourself in Chrome's developer tools (or the equivalent in your browser of choice).

---

**UPDATE**

The [HTML 5 spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) is a good place to learn about this. If I'm understanding it correctly, `h1`, `h2`, etc. are "flow content" and expect "phrasing content" to be nested inside (not other flow content). I'm new to reading this spec, so I may be misunderstanding the structure of the document. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Code academy said that tags can be nested, but it didn't specify that these specific tags could not be nested. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: You can't nest block level elements like paragraph and heading tags. You can only nest inline elements like span, bold, etc.

Comment: Yes. Expecting phrasing content means nesting heading elements is *invalid*. The reason the <h4> tag closes <h1> element is in the parsing spec. [It says](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#ref-for-stack-of-open-elements-67) `A start tag whose tag name is one of: "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6" ... If the current node is an HTML element whose tag name is one of "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", or "h6", then ... pop the current node off the stack of open elements.` Note that it only looks at the current element, so `<h1><span><h4>...</h4></span></h1>` will nest though it is still invalid.

Comment: Also note that phrasing content is a *subset* of flow content, not a complementary grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this used `span` tag instated of nesting head tag.
Like this :

```
<h1>
        First text.
        <span> 
             I'm a different size than the first text. 
        </span> 

        I'm not the same size as the first text. Why?
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 span{ 
      font-size:20px;
      display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags are [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like `<p>` tags. You can think of them taking up a whole line. Thus with your example you're trying to squeeze a whole line inside of a full line. It just won't fit. Your browser probably assumes you meant to have a `</h1>` right before the `<h4>` tag in your example. Thus the remaining text after the `</h4>` tag is just seen as plain text and the closing `</h1>` tag is simply ignored.

If you want switch between h1 text and h4 text. you need something like this:

```
<h1>first text.</h1>
<h4>I'm a different size than the first text.</h4>
<h1>I'm now the same size as the first text</h1>
```

If for some inexplicable reason, you want the h1,h4,h1 tags in the same line. You'll need to use css. You could add a class, then set them as inline block. However, if you just want to change the styling of text in a line, you should use span tags instead.